# SeriLog Azure sync dropping }}?

Tags: azure-table-storage, serilog

Request logs with missing characters.

In Program.cs I set up Serilog using

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>().UseSerilog();
```

appsettings.json has

```
 "Serilog": {
   "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.AzureTableStorage" ],
```

My code logs a object object using

```
Using SeriLog
// etc
Log.Log.Information("REQUEST:" + Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
```

When I query the log using

```
    public void GetData()
    {
        var info = new StorageInfo();
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(info.ConnectionString);
        var query = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual,DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-1).Date);
        var exQuery = new TableQuery<LogEntity>().Where(query);   
        var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference(info.TableName);
        var results = table.ExecuteQuery(exQuery);  
        foreach (LogEntity entity in results.OrderBy(x=>x.Timestamp))
        {
             var s =$"log: {entity.PartitionKey},  \t{entity.RenderedMessage},\t{entity.Timestamp},\t{entity.Timestamp.Millisecond} ms";
            Trace.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

However when I copy and paste the output into VSCode and format as Json I see that some closing curly brackets are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that you're not making `request` be a message-insert, as one generally should.

```
Log.Log.Information("REQUEST:" + Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
```

should become:

```
Log.Information("REQUEST: {request}", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
```

I recommend reading https://serilog.net/ and [the serilog wiki](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki) as it provides good background and examples.

The [Serilog Analyzer](https://github.com/Suchiman/SerilogAnalyzer) tool is very helpful for pointing things like this out on the fly as you edit in VS.